# SessionAttribute and SpringFramework

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, session-variables

How can I set session attribute using spring framework and annotation?

Something equivalent to

```
 request.getSession().setAttribute("key", "value");
```

Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with the code you posted? It's short and obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass session as an attribute of controller's method and then use it directly without request.getSession(), however it isn't a big improvement and there are no annotations :)

```
public String handleRequest(HttpSession session) {
    session.setAttribute("key", "value");
}
```

EDIT:

You can also add attribute to ModelMap instance and then use @SessionAtributes annotation in these controller definitions in which you want to have that attribute inside ModelMap: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-sessionattrib

Comment: Yes I was trying to use @SessionAttributes but it doesnt make sense yet.

Comment: You can also use `WebUtils.setSessionAttribute`